# Beautifulsoup escape invalid xml characters before parsing

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I need to parse excel 97 XML documents that contain lines like the one below:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s21" ss:Formula="=IF(RC[-1]<>0,RC[-23]/RC[-1],0)"> <Data ss:Type="Number"></Data>
</Cell>
```

If I understand correctly the "<" and ">" characters need to be escaped but aren't. So when I used beautiful soup to parse this or lxml, it throws an exception or just stops when it encounters the first of those characters. I'd like to escape these characters with &lt, &gt etc so I can read in the document.

The files are massive and there are 100s of them so I'd need this to be atleast somewhat fast. The encoding is listed as cp-1252 if that helps anything.

Whats the best way to escape these invalid characters to beautiful soup can actually read in the file?